# How to count the number of occurrences of a string in a file and append it within another file

Tags: python, file, count

I need to count the number of occurrences of 'Product ID' in the .txt file and have it print the number within that file. I'm new to python and trying to wrap my head around this. I have it working separately in the code, but it prints the number to the command line after running the program (hence the print). I tried using print(count) >> "hardDriveSummary.txt file" and print >> count, "hardDriveSummary.txt file" but can't get it to work.

```
# Read .xml file and putlines row_name and Product ID into new .txt file
search = 'row_name', 'Product ID'

#source file
with open('20190211-131516_chris_Hard_Drive_Order.xml') as f1:
    #output file
    with open('hardDriveSummary.txt', 'wt') as f2:
        lines = f1.readlines()
        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            if line.startswith(search):
                f2.write("\n" + line)

#count how many occurances of 'Product ID' in .txt file
def main():

    file  = open('hardDriveSummary.txt', 'r').read()
    team  = "Product ID"
    count = file.count(team)

    print(count)

main()
```

Sample of hardDriveSummary.txt:

```
Name          Country 1

Product ID                      : 600GB

Name         Country 2

Product ID                      : 600GB

Name           Country 1

Product ID                      : 450GB
```

Contents of .xml file:

```
************* Server Summary *************

Server                      serv01
label                         R720
asset_no                   CNT3NW1
Name                     Country 1
name.1                       City1
Unnamed: 6                     NaN

************* Drive Summary **************

ID                              : 0:1:0
State                           : Failed
Product ID                      : 600GB
Serial No.                      : 6SL5KF5G


************* Server Summary *************

Server                      serv02
label                         R720
asset_no                   BZYGT03
Name                     Country 2
name.1                       City2
Unnamed: 6                     NaN

************* Drive Summary **************

ID                              : 0:1:0
State                           : Failed
Product ID                      : 600GB
Serial No.                      : 6SL5K75G


************* Server Summary *************

Server                      serv03
label                         R720
asset_no                   5GT4N51
Name                     Country 1
name.1                       City1  
Unnamed: 6                     NaN

************* Drive Summary **************

ID                              : 0:1:0
State                           : Failed
Product ID                      : 450GB
Serial No.                      : 6S55K5MG
```

Comment: is "Product ID" two different words

Comment: Hi @Jeril, it is two different words in the db where it's originally getting pulled from before going into the xml file.

Comment: Kindly check my solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply just want to tag the counter value onto the end of the file the following code should work:

```
import os

def main():   
    with open('hardDriveSummary.txt', 'ab+') as f:
        term = "Product ID"
        count = f.read().count(term)
        f.seek(os.SEEK_END)  # Because we've already read the entire file. Go to the end before writing otherwise we get an IOError
        f.write('\n'+str(count))
```

Comment: Thanks @cullzie. I added your portion to the code but it's not showing in the .txt file. I've added a sample of the file in my post in case it makes a difference. Thanks again!

Comment: It's working fine for me with the text file you provided. Can you update the question with the xml snippet so I can run the whole script? Also what version of python are you using?

Comment: Hi @cullzie, I've added the contents of the xml file. I had to scrub it too.

Comment: Ok I've ran the whole thing now and it is still writing the count to the file fine. Just a thing to note your .xml file isn't in xml format. You should rename it to a .txt file to avoid confusion. Output on my side with sample data:  `
Product ID                      : 600GB

Product ID                      : 600GB

Product ID                      : 450GB

3`

Comment: Hi @cullzie. I've tried with main() at the end and without (like your example) and without main() I get nothing, but with main() I get '0'. :(

Comment: Hi @culzie, OK it's working! I tried on another server that uses 2.7.5. The one I test on is using 2.7.15. That's the only difference I can see. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since `Product ID` is two different words, you split the entire text to two word groups, the following code will give you the expected results:

```
from collections import Counter
f = open(r"sample.py", "r")
words = f.read().split()
bigrams = zip(words, words[1:])
counts = Counter(bigrams)
data = {' '.join(k): v for k, v in dict(counts).items()}
if 'Product ID' in data:
    print('Count of "Product ID": ', data['Product ID'])
```